# how do I make my irc public

Tags: irc

I've recently been trying to make an IRC server on my home network (just a bunch of friends will be joining so I am not to worried about security) and I can't figure out how to allow my friends to join

I've tried port forwarding on my Netgear router, though it is connected to a different router, downstairs, I did however open port 6667 on the original router for the netgear one.

How do I make my irc network public and allow people to join?

the server was made according to this tutorial
https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-irc-server/

(raspberry pi 4 4g ram ubuntu lts)

Comment: so the pi is behind double NAT? i.e. is the "different router" WAN connected to the "netgear router" LAN?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/10m4bxu this is how my router is setup according to netgear

Comment: that's pretty, but in no way does it answer the question - where's the pi? where's the "different router"?

Comment: so basically I have a ziggo router downstairs, connected with ethernet cable I have another one upstairs, and from that my pc and Pi are connected to the internet so its  ziggo router ---> wan ---> router netgear -----> LAN ----> Raspi

Comment: You are seriously underestimating the security risk, both to you and your friends.

Comment: You should clarify whether you need a static internet IP or not as per my other comment.  Pretty sure you do -- meaning, unless you already know you don't because _____, you do.  Simply communicating what it currently is at any given point will probably not work because your ISP likely blocks incoming connection attempts.

Comment: I've tried making my IP public, but that's not possible, all you can do is to buy a Public IP to get connected from anywhere.

Comment: Look into the following networking topics: 1) NAT forwarding, 2) Dynamic DNS (DDNS) service. You may set these up outside the Raspberry Pi, for example, in the router and using another computer.

Comment: @Krishna You can get around that via a dynamic DNS service, which is quite a bit cheaper than a genuine static IP, at least for residential LANs.  See answers to the duplicate question.